# How to send email from delegated account using Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

I have created an automated google script to send notification email on periodic basis but I want mail to be send from my delegated account since I logged in using my primary email, so I can't send it through my delegated email account.

I tried to achieve the same using send email as functionality but it is not working, recipients are receiving mails from my primary address.

Please provide your inputs

Thanks

Comment: Show your mcve.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/cant-send-email-on-behalf-of-delegated-email-address

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried the same thing as mentioned in the shared link about the use of send mail as option to send email from your primary account using delegated email address. When I compose a mail select the secondary email address in dropdrop of "from" and try to send it to my primary email and other recepient then only I can see the mail is coming from secondary email but other recepient getting email from my primary address it should be from secondary address I do not know where  I went wrong. Please help

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the delegated account in your usual inbox. Go to:

> Settings>Accounts>Send mail as:>add another email address

Make sure that the "Treat as alias" checkbox is checked; submit and verify the request.

Second, you can access all the aliases with `GmailApp.getAliases()`.

Finally, you are able to choose the alias with the Gmail Draft or Message Services by changing the `from` field in the `option` object.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#update(String,String,String,Object)